# count total price of items in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT sum(CASE
             WHEN user_ad_type = '2' THEN
               10
             WHEN user_ad_type = '3' THEN
               15
             WHEN user_ad_telegram != '' OR user_ad_telegram IS NOT NULL THEN
               3
             WHEN user_ad_website != '' OR user_ad_website IS NOT NULL THEN
               3
             ELSE
               0
           END) sum
       FROM ads
       WHERE user_id = 57
```

But it does not count the sum of all of the items correctly. look at my table:
**[click here to open img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFSCK.png).**

So the sum of all of the items should be **21** but **[if you take a look at this img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XRM9.png)**, you will see it count **15**.
Because **`user_ad_type  + user_ad_telegram  + user_ad_website`** is not null or have special values and sum of this items is 21. What's wrong?

I even tested this:

```
SELECT sum(CASE
             WHEN user_ad_type = '2' THEN
               10
             WHEN user_ad_type = '3' THEN
               15
             WHEN user_ad_telegram IS NOT NULL THEN
               3
             WHEN user_ad_website IS NOT NULL THEN
               3
             ELSE
               0
           END) sum
       FROM ads
       WHERE user_id = 57
```

But it still doesn't count all of the items.

I want to check that if some of the column is **not null** or have **special values**, then **add price to them** and get **total price of that items**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want separate sums:

```
SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN user_ad_type = '2' THEN 10
                 WHEN user_ad_type = '3'
                 THEN 15
            END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN user_ad_telegram <> '' THEN 3 ELSE 0 END) + -- handles NULL as well
        SUM(CASE WHEN user_ad_website <> '' THEN 3 ELSE 0 END)
       ) as sum
FROM ads
WHERE user_id = 57;
```